# "Indent" or "push down" headers one level in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, headers

I have a series of headers, level 1-x, and now I discovered I should group them under two headers. Is there a way to "indent" or "push down" the headers so that, for the ones I have selected, level 1 becomes 2, 2 becomes 3 and so on?

Comment: Don't forget to mark the issue as resolved by accepting your answer

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Thanks! That's the problem with this long delay before allowed to mark your own answer... you move on and forget 

Comment: You may be interested in [*View my questions with unaccepted answers*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16869/351462) and [*How can I view all my unaccepted questions across SE?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119575/351462)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And after asking the question, an idea popped into my head, and it worked.

1. Open the navigation pane
2. Right-click a header, and choose `Demote`.

This will push the header with all its sub-headers down one level. Unfortunately it seems I can't select several headers though... but sure quicker than doing it for both top and sub-headers.